# Http post request with Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: post, httpclient, access-token, url-encoding

How to sent POST request with content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Given an access code, I am trying to get the AccessToken using POST request where I have all the information set in POST URL so i don't know what to pass as Http content in the postAysnc method.

According to another post For application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the body of the HTTP message sent to the server is essentially one giant query string -- name/value pairs are separated by the ampersand (&), and names are separated from values by the equals symbol (=). An example of this would be:

MyVariableOne=ValueOne&MyVariableTwo=ValueTwo.

So I have similar case where my POST url has all the information as querystring, in that case I don't know what to pass as HttpContent in the postAysnc method since its a mandatory parameter

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
StringContent queryString = new StringContent(data);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), queryString );

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

1. Continue to use `StringContent`, but set the content type: `new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`
2. Instead of using `StringContent`, use `FormUrlEncodedContent`; note that this takes in a sequence of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` describing the values (so for example create a dictionary containing `{ {"MyVariableOne", "ValueOne"}, {"MyVariableTwo", "ValueTwo"} }`